# Kill and free the memory of never ending threads from main in perl

Tags: perl

There is main running and two threads running,The two threads are infinite event loops where we are waiting for some event,
The issue is I want to wait for the event to come for some finite amount of time and then exit from the program

But when I am exiting the threads are still running
I want to free all the space occupied by this threads and then exit from the script

How to fix this?

How to do a clean up before I exit

How to kill threads that are never ending

Answer (score 0):

Process running your script ends when your script ends. Operation system is responsible to free all resource allocated by this process including all threads. Do you observe opposite? If so, fill bug report to your operation system.